# Using Ajax how can I match a drop down menu selection value from a form to records in my database and fetch associated record/row to prefill a form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a drop down menu with selections ...I need to match the value of a selection to the value of that in my database under the column (invoiceid) and then fetch associated record/row of form data to prefill my form when my prefill button is clicked.  Below is as far as I've gotten I feel like I'm close if even that.  I can't figure out what I'm missing or how to make this code work.  Much appreciation and Thanks to anyone's help in advance.

**FORM**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#">


        <select name="dropdown-select" id="dropdown-select">
            <option value="invoiceidselection1">invoiceidselection1</option>
            <option value="invoiceidselection2">invoiceidselection2</option>
        </select>

         <button id="submit-id">Prefill Form</button>


        <input id="location" name="location" required="" type="text">

        <input onclick="change" id="q1" name="q1" value="4.99" checked="checked" type="radio">

        <input name="subcheck" value="0" type="hidden">
        <input id="subcheck" name="subcheck" value="1" onclick="return false" checked="" type="checkbox">Agree to Terms of Service


    <button id="btn1" type="submit" name="Submit">Submit</button>


</form>




<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
     $(function(){


        $('#submit-id').on('click', function(e){  // Things to do when 'Submit Id' button is clicked
            var invoiceid = $('#dropdown-select').val(); // Grab user id from text field
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submit, we are submiting form down with ajax.

             $.ajax({
              url: "orders.php",
              data: {

               }
            }).done(function(data) {
data = JSON.parse(data);
$('#location').val(data.location);
$('#q1').val(data.q1);
$('#subcheck').val(data.subcheck);
});
        });
     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**orders.php**

```
<?php

// Create the connection to the database
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");


// Check if the connection failed
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  die();
}



  if (isset($_GET['dropdown-select']))
{
    $dropdown-select= $_GET['dropdown-select'];

   $query = "SELECT location, q1, subcheck
        FROM seguin_orders
  WHERE invoiceid = '".($dropdown-select)."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))c{
 echo json_encode($row);
 die(); 
} 


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))c{
 echo json_encode($row);
 die(); // assuming there is just one row
}
```

Now in the JavaScript end

```
.done(function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#location').val(data.location);
    $('#q1').val(data.q1);
    $('#subcheck').val(data.subcheck);
});
```

I'm assuming the the table has the following columns `location`, `q1` and `subcheck`.

**edits**

You also need to send the get parameters with your request. In `$.ajax`. Set `data` to:

```
    {
        'dropdown-select': invoiceid
    }
```

Its better to use `$.get`

```
$.get('orders.php', {
     'dropdown-select': invoiceid
 }).done(function (data) { .....});
```

If it still does not work.. Remove `data=JSON.parse(data)`

Hope it works now.

Comment: thanks...both above asumptions are correct...however i tried modifying my code using your provided code and nothing happens when i click the prefill button...Im thinking maybe somthing would go  between $.ajax({
              url: "orders.php",
              data: {
------am I missing somthing inbetween here?-------
               }
            }).done(function(data) {.....not sure what im missing thanks for your help though

Comment: tried everything u suggested...still no prefill...thanks for your time n effort